# Json "Parser Error" from server to client

Tags: jquery, json, asp-classic

I use an asp (classic) utility file to create json objects from an SQL database, see:
http://code.google.com/p/aspjson/

here is what I get from the server side:

```
{"results":[{"Opt_Name":"BARR","Opt_FirstName":"TomTest","Comp_Name":"My_Company"}]}
```

Which is valid json, at least valid for jsonlint.

BUT this never triggers my callback function (Fetch) and I get a ParserError from my error function (myFunc) down here:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    function myfunc(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert("call failed " + textStatus + "   error   " + errorThrown + "   Xhr " + XMLHttpRequest);
    }

    $.ajaxSetup({
        error:myfunc
    });

    $.getJSON("jsonGETdataTest.asp", Fetch);

    function Fetch(data)
    {
        alert("blop");
    }
});
```

I don't know what to do next!

If anyone has a lead on this one I'll be very gratefull.
Thanks for stoping by anyway.

Comment: to make an alert of "data" in Fetch function, do you see out [object]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,
Thanks everyone for helping, 
it looks as I have finally found an answer!

> for asp-classic

```
 response.AddHeader "Content-type", "text/json"
```

That was the missing part of my response :-s

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for asp, but in PHP the correct string will be '[{"Opt_Name":"BARR","Opt_FirstName":"TomTest","Comp_Name":"My_Company"}]'.
In PHP I don't have the "results" before.

Comment: Well thanks Cesar but, 
as I said earlier the json formating is correct,
I have tried the one you suggest, but It still give a "parsererror".
Because I'll use it in an YUI datasource I want to stick to the formating example they give here:

var dsLocalJSON = new YAHOO.util.LocalDataSource({
    found: 3,
    total: 20,
    results:
        [{name: "apples", type:"fruit", color: "red"},
        {name: "broccoli", type:"veg", color: "green"},
        {name: "cherries", type:"fruit", color: "red"}]
});

see:
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datasource/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$.getJSON("jsonGETdataTest.asp", Fetch);

    function Fetch(data)
    {
        alert("blop");
    }
```

try something like this:

```
$.getJSON("jsonGETdataTest.asp", function(data){
    ...do something with data object...
    });
```

see http://docs.jquery.com/GetJSON

Comment: Thanks Jack,
but both ways are correct, 
I think it has nothing to do with javascript syntax.
Somehow the jquery getJSON function doesn't like what it gets from the server side, even though it's valid json.
I have googled quite a lot about this "parser Error" but nothing relevant was to be found so far.